# Get Checked Only in <Select multiple>

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to get only the checked names in a list of names. Here is my code model:

```html
<select ng-model="selectTopic" ng-change="changedTopic(selectTopic)" ng-options="option as option for option in topics">>
    <option value="" disabled>Select a Subject</option>
</select>

<select ng-model="selectDept" ng-change="changedDepartment(selectDept)" ng-options="option as option for option in department">
    <option value="" disabled>Select a Department</option>
</select> 
      
<select ng-model="selectUser" ng-options="option as option for option in users" multiple="multiple">
 <option value="" disabled>Select a User</option>  
</select>
```

I want to get the selected topic, department, and users. I am currently using: console.log($scope.topics + $scope.departments + $scope.users) but it returns everything. I just want to return the selected items.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: The selected items will be available in the variables bound using the ng-model directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to print the ng-models , not the arrays:

```
console.log($scope.selectTopic);
console.log($scope.selectDept);
console.log($scope.selectUser);
```

Hope it helps =)

Answer (score 0):

use one object for the model in your form , then you have all the user input in that one object which makes it simple to send to server or to reset form

```
$scope.userInput={}

<select ng-model="userInput.selectTopic" ng-change="changedTopic(userInput.selectTopic)" ng-options='...'>
<select ng-model="userInput.selectDept" ng-change="changedDepartment(userInput.selectDept)"  ng-options='...'>
```

to see this working put the following in your view temporarily

```
<pre>{{userInput|json}}</pre>
```